# AngularJs - apply condition on ng-click

Tags: angularjs

I am making a angularjs app and in this I have a list of users coming from`ng-repeat`. Now whenever I click on any user a new div box opens. But the problem is that there are multiple boxes opening for the same user and I want only one box for one user.
I tried using `ng-if` but failed.
I am sharing my code, please check it and provide solutions, thanks in advance.

Code from List of user are coming :

```
      <div class="people">
            <div ng-repeat="user in vm.otherUsers | filter : vm.search">
                <div directive class="person" ng-click="vm.activateChat(user);bubble=true;" id="chat_{{user.id}}" ng-disabled="true">
                    <img alt="" />
                    <span class="name" >{{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}} 
                        <span ng-if="!bubble && user.counter>0" class="noti_bubble">{{user.counter}}</span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and on click activateChat opens the new box for that user.
Code for the box is:

```
      <div ng-repeat="chatUser in vm.multipleUsers">

        <div class="msg_box" id="d_{{chatUser.id}}">
                --box content--
        </div>
       </div>
```

Note: Only one box should open for a single user

Comment: I couldn't see code which opens box. Does box mean a model box? What is `directive` in your code, please provide its code?

Comment: Please give the json of variable "vm". I think it should be user.multipleUsers instead of vm.multipleUsers. But can give proper solution after getting json of "Vm"

Answer (score 0):

You could keep a list of opened boxes per userId in your controller. Then add a function to your controller that you can use in an ng-if or ng-class to show a non-clickable version of your div. Use the same list to check if you should open a new modal in vm.activateChat()